# can't type in INSERT LINK box or paste embedded video code in tinymce

Tags: hyperlink, tinymce, embed

I have a tinymce that init's like this:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    theme: "modern",
    plugins: [
"advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
"searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
"insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"

});
```

At first, this appears to work OK but If I click the INSERT LINK button the dialog comes up, but I can't type in the input fields. The same goes for pasting embedded video code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My problem was that I was displaying the tinymce in a blockUI element, which was blocking the extra input elements. I probably need to unblock them specifically.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I was displaying the tinymce in a blockUI element, which was blocking the extra input elements. I probably need to unblock them specifically